# Extend stock chart date

Tags: anychart

Is it possible to extend the stock chart beyond the date of data being passed in?

For example, at 9:30am, I'd like to show the data that I have, but have the time range of the chart extend out to 4pm and show no data.

(Almost like a live view as the stock is being generated.)

I have tried adjusting the ranges, but it seems the chart just adapts to the data I have. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Currently, we can offer you the workaround: the additional null points will create the necessary empty space.